# How to enable the RFS in Bootstrap v 4.5.x CDN

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive, cdn

I'm reading the bootstrap doc and I read this ... Bootstrap v4.3 ships with the option to enable responsive font sizes, allowing the text to scale more naturally across device and viewport sizes.RFS can be enabled by changing the $enable-responsive-font-sizes Sass variable to true.

My question is, how can I enable this feature with CDN Bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#responsive-font-sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use CDN you can add the following.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/coliff/bootstrap-rfs/bootstrap-rfs.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with the CDN version. It says that you need to re-compile bootstrap yourself to get RFS to work. So you need to install the source using npm.

> Bootstrap v4.3 ships with the option to enable responsive font sizes, allowing text to scale more naturally across device and viewport sizes. **RFS can be enabled by changing the $enable-responsive-font-sizes Sass variable to true and recompiling Bootstrap**.

Comment: ooh okee thaks bro